# Collection view crashing on cell.viewWithTag(100)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

i am trying to implement the collection vie as described in [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

it is crashing on the following line

```
let gelleryImageView: UIImageView = (cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView)
```

with

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

my imageView is the only child of the reusable cell and the imageView has the tag of `100`

[image]

[image]

Rest of method

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell
    print(cell.subviews.count)


    let gelleryImageView: UIImageView = (cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView)

    gelleryImageView.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: a tutorial recommending you to use tags (and not telling you why it's a bad idea) is a bad tutorial. how have you checked the tag is 100?

Comment: It was set in interface builder in the attributes inspector

Comment: you said it is 100, i asked how you know it's 100, did you check it at runtime? your error suggests it isn't actually 100. perhaps the image view isn't even a subview...

Comment: yes sorry misread your comment. I have added 2 screenshots if that helps.

Comment: you need to debug and check the truth at runtime - probably you're either editing the tag or instantiating the cell from something other than the NIB / storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing the cell image via tag. Create a custom cell class and create an outlet for the imageView and access it that way.

remove line from viewdidload()

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

//

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryCollectionViewCell

    cell.galleryImage.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error tells you that something you are force-unwrapping with "!" is actually nil.

Until you get used to optionals, don't use force-unwrap. It's dangerous.

Instead, use "if let" optional binding, or a guard statement, or some other approach that lets you gracefully fail if the optional contains a nil.

In your case it is likely that there is no view with the tag of 100, so it's returning nil. If you didn't use force-unwrapping you'd be able

See this thread I created covering the topic:

[How to deal with "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683813/im-getting-an-error-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-op)